ExpressJS Postman POST request body is undefined
I am using the light version of Postman 11.0.12 on a Windows 10 server.
My body values always returns undefined.
If I use Query Params then key returns the correct value.
I suspect could it be this version of Postman? Based on setup I cannot used the web version nor desktop version on my Win 11 as I think Postman doesn't work with 11 yet.
I've even copied the code for CURL and tried it via a CMD window but still same issue.
Am I missing something simple....
ExpressJS:
const sql = require('mssql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5001;

//SQL settings
//--------------
// const config = {
//     user: bobbeat,
// } 



//insert stock
const postStock = `INSERT INTO [DEV].[dbo].[stocks]
           (code]
           ,[ID])
     VALUES `;

let resultRows = [];

function queryDB(tableParam, stockID, addStockParams) {
    const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

    const connectionString = config;


    let tableToQuery = tableParam ===
                         : tableParam === 'postStock' ? postStock + '(' + addStockParams + ')'
                         : 'No table found';
    
    sql.query(connectionString, tableToQuery, (err, rows) => {
        rows ? console.log('rows returned') : console.log('errors are ', err)
        resultRows.push(rows);
    });
}
    
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World! from nodejs')
})

//post stock
app.post('/api/v1/postStock', (req, res) => {
    //cannot get whole body via req.body but query param works
    //1
    //let stockBody = [ "req.body.code"];
    console.log(req.query.code);

    //2
    //post stock to db
    //queryDB('postStock', null,  req.query.code);

    //return result
    res.send('resultRows');
});

//monitoring feature
app.get('/running', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Api is up and PM2 monitoring');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

POSTMAN - POST - (raw, JSON) - not working:
{
  "code": "abc"
}

Result:
undefined

Query params - working:
http://localhost:5001/api/v1/postStock?code=abc

Result:
C:\BuildRunJSTools>node getSQLapi.js
=> type object
Example app listening on port 5001
abc


Does this answer your question? Express.js req.body undefined

Yes that did thanks. Is it an absolute must we use middleware parsers? I am wondering if there's any other way other than bodyparser (old days) or can we do something like this: JSON.stringify(req.body.code) ?

yeah, see Expressjs raw body but you'd be reinventing the wheel sooner than later. in short that's how express works: you use what you need, when you need, where you need it: Using middleware

Great! That helps and deffo don't want to re invent the wheel :-)
